# How to restrict access to php website for users from home?

Tags: php

i have a php application for a company, using MySql Database, what i want is there any way to restrict the users to access to their accounts from home? since we are not using a static IP's

Comment: If you don't want to let users who are not logged in to access any of your php (except for `login.php`), you can use `sessions`. Use this if there is a logged in user during the browser's session

Comment: @CarlJan — What is the connection between "being at home" and "not being able to log in"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches:

- Host the site on a company LAN so it isn't accessible over the Internet
- Get a static IP address (you're a company, you should be able to get an Internet connection which comes with static IPs, my consumer ADSL package comes with one!).
- Perform authentication with [client side SSL certificates](https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm) and install them on the browsers of the office computers

Comment: The problem with first and second options is because we use this program worldwide in some countries. i will try the third option, Thanks

Comment: "The problem with first and second options is because we use this program worldwide in some countries" — VPN would solve that for the first. Getting a static IP for each site would solve it for the second.

Comment: so, in my case what is your advice? VPN ?

Comment: I don't recommend any of these options over the others, especially not in general terms.